# Identify $P(2014)$ if $P(i)=1/i$ for every positive integer $1\le i\le2013$

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

> Suppose $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $2012$ and $P(x) = 1/x$ when $x$ takes the integer values $1\cdots2013$ (inclusive). What is the value of $P(2014)$?

I get $1/1007$ but I'm not sure if it's right, and my method is very inelegant.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that $x\cdot P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $2013$ that attains the value $1$ in the $2013$ points $1,2,\dotsc,2013$. So

$$x\cdot P(x) = 1 + c\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{2013} (x-k).$$

Now, $x\cdot P(x)$ evidently attains the value $0$ in $x = 0$, so

$$0 = 1 + c\cdot (-1)^{2013}\cdot 2013!$$

or $c = \dfrac{1}{2013!}$. Then

$$2014\cdot P(2014) = 1 + \frac{1}{2013!}\cdot 2013! = 2,$$

and indeed

$$P(2014) = \frac{2}{2014} = \frac{1}{1007}.$$

Comment: What an extremely clever answer!