# If $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree 3 such that $p(i) = {1\over1+i}$ for all $a=\{1,2,3,4\}$. Then find $p(5)$.

Tags: functions, polynomials

If $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $3$ such that $p(i)$ = $\frac{1}{1+i}$ for all $a=\{1,2,3,4\}$. Then find $p(5)$.

> My attempt : (1) First obviously I thought of solving the four
>   equations which can be generated by assuming polynomial as
>   $ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+d$. But that would be a very lengthy solution.
>
> (2) In other attempt, I let
>
> $g(x)=p(x) - \frac1{1+x}$ believing that some calculus concepts might be
>   applicable since $g(x)=0$ at $1,2,3,4$ but I couldn't think of anything
>   that works out.
>
> Also, we "cannot" make $g(x) =k(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$ since we can only
>   write that for polynomials since we can comment on their maximum
>   number of real roots by looking at the degree.
>
> That rules out another possible method.

So, how can this question be solved?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: You've been here long enough to use MathJax.

Comment: Why is (1) so bad? That's just 4 unknowns, so a $4x4$ matrix with integer entries that needs to be reduced, that doesn't look that hard to me. Of course there might be a really deep, nice concept here to make it easier, but such a concept has to be found and proven first, which will most likely take more time than just row elimination on a $4 x 4$ matrix.

Comment: I am sorry, I wrote that in a rush. I have made the edits..

Comment: Consider $h(x) = (x+1)p(x) - 1$ rather than $g$.

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether to call this a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640372/p0lyn0mial-questi0n).

Comment: @Daniel Fischer If I write $h(x)=(x+1) p(x)-1$=$k(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$ how will I find k?

Comment: What is $h(-1)$?

Comment: Did you mean $p(i)=\frac{1}{i+1}$ for all $i=\{1,2,3,4\}$? Instead of $a$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identify $P(2014)$ if $P(i)=1/i$ for every positive integer $1\le i\le2013$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640372/identify-p2014-if-pi-1-i-for-every-positive-integer-1-le-i-le2013)

Answer (score 4):

I am writing this answer based on the hints provided by Daniel Fischer( in the comments section) so that others can also benefit from this answer.

Consider a polynomial function $h(x)=p(x)(x+1)-1$

$x=1,2,3,4$ are clearly the roots of this polynomial therefore $h(x)$ can also be written as

$h(x)=k(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$

So, **$h(x)=p(x)(x+1)-1=k(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)$----(1)**

To find the value of k, we put $x=-1$ in (1)

( *why? Because it would make p(x) vanish, so we wouldn't need more values of p(x) to find k)*

Putting $x=-1$, $0-1=k(-2)(-3)(-4)(-5)$

This gives $k=\frac{-1}{120}$

Now to find $p(5)$,

we put $x=5$ in eq(1),  this gives the value of $p(5)=\frac{2}{15}$